# Mocking class methods with OCMock not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock, class-method

What's wrong with this code? Trying to make a class method return @NO, but it's returning @YES (the NSLog prints "1").

```
// Make the test think you don't have any internet
id mockFunctions = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[Functions class]];
[[[mockFunctions stub] andReturnValue:@NO] connectionAvailable];


NSLog(@"derp: %hhd", [Functions connectionAvailable]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had two copies of the class that was being mocked. By not including the .m file in the test target, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

The construction for `andReturnValue` is a little more complex than what you are doing.

```
[[[mockFunctions stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE((BOOL){NO})] connectionAvailable];
```

Give that a try and see if it works.

Comment: I can see that I had that error in my code, but NSLog is still giving me 1, and break points reveal that it's still calling that class method.